# Trig: Using the proper identity to calculate $\cos 165^\circ$

Tags: trigonometry

If we had to find $\cos 165^\circ$, can't we use either the sum/difference identity for cosine or the half-angle identity for cosine?

Does it matter which one we choose?

Comment: $$165=120+45$$ which is easier as no sign check required. OR $$\sqrt2\cos165^\circ=-\sqrt{1+\cos330^\circ}$$

Comment: Well, the way I see it, the first one requires me to know cos120, but simplicity of the task aside--wouldn't both yield the correct answer?

Comment: Yes, we could use either a sum/difference identity for cosine or the half/angle identity for cosine.   That said, I would also recommend using the sum of angles formula for cosine.

Comment: @Matt Both identities will yield the same answer, so the only reason to choose one over the other is convenience, simplicity, ease of computation, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes can. One of the simplest ways is
$$\cos\dfrac{11\pi}{12}=\cos\Bigl(\pi-\dfrac{\pi}{12}\Bigr)=-\cos\Bigl(\dfrac{\pi}{12}\Bigr)=-\sqrt\frac{1+\cos\frac\pi6}2.$$

It relies on the identities:
$$\cos(\pi-x)=-\cos x,\qquad \cos^2 x=\frac{1+\cos 2x}2.$$

Comment: Is it possible to obtain a "different looking" answer? Perhaps an identity? If we use two different methods to obtain the same answer?

Comment: I've added the identities used in the answer – and I found there was a typo in it, which is fixed  now. Are these the details you want?